# Update jquery variable value in realtime according to div width

Tags: jquery, variables, real-time

I am using JQMap Route Calc plugin which must have set width to display properly. To display custom width depending on devices screen resolution I used $(".locationmap").width() value to count its width according to its parent div. Now I would like to know how is possible to update that value in realtime and reload that div in case that user switch screen from portrait to landscape mode. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

The full call looks like:

```
$('.locationmap').JQMap({
    jqm_Height : 450,
    jqm_Width : $(".locationmap").width(),
    jqm_StartOpacity : 7,              
    jqm_OverlayColor : '#000',
    jqm_Fixdestination : '[[*Map Location]]',
    jqm_ZoomStartPoint : 14
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.locationMap').resize(function() {
     //Your code in here
});
```

This is called everytime a div with class locationMap is resized

Comment: I am trying it like this:
$('.locationmap').resize(function() {
  $('.locationmap').JQMap({
    jqm_Height : 450,
    jqm_Width : $(".locationmap").width(),
    jqm_StartOpacity : 7,              
    jqm_OverlayColor : '#000',
    jqm_Fixdestination : '[[*Map Location]]',
    jqm_ZoomStartPoint : 14
  });
});

But div is empty without map